# reexport all files from a folder webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

We're using a folder structure like this

```
components
  | Button.js
  | Nav.js
  | ...etc
  | index.js

somefolder
  |somefile.js
```

in the inderx file we're importing every component and reexporting it like this

```js
 // index.js
  import Button from './Button'
  import Nav from './Nav'

  export {Button, Nav}
```

this way we can import many components into a file like this

```js
 // somefile.js
  import {Button, Nav} from '../components'
```

Maintaining that index file is a bit of a pain though and discourages flexible use of components. I know that Webpack can import many files with a syntax like this

```js
function requireAll(r) { r.keys().forEach(r); }
requireAll(require.context('./components/', true, /\.js$/));
```

however, I didn't yet find a way to reexport all of these components to use them like above.

The **desired outcome** is to replace the `index.js` file with something that **automates the process of bundling all the files from a folder without having to add every file manually.**

Answer (score 0):

I think getting rid of the file index will not be the best solution and may cause questions from other developers. But I can offer a slightly more simplified way:

index.js:

```
export * from './some-component1.js';
export * from './some-component2.js';
```

some-component1.js:

```
export {SomeComponent1};
```

some-component2.js:

```
export {SomeComponent2};
```